# how my makefile aotumatically change .o prerequisite to .c targets?

Tags: makefile, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

[here](http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=2012e4d44ea69e176560e72a2d8b4355&sub=AAA4635A6B834A0ABB1E2A9B109C7808) is my `Make file`.
look at target `olmenu-proto1`,  it depends on `olmenu-proto1_yacc.o`
But I haven't define any target called `olmenu-proto1_yacc.o`.
Interestingly, when I invoke `make olmenu-proto1`,it works!
Strangely enough!
I want to know why it would do this, thank you!

Comment: the makefile is in the following answer posted by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include the relevant bits of your makefile in your question, rather than asking people to follow a link to another site.  Especially one where it's impossible to view unless you enable a lot of javascript, which many people leave mostly disabled.

In any event, most likely the reason is because make can envision how to create targets by chaining together rules, even if you don't list the prerequisites explicitly.  For more information see [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) in the GNU make manual.

Comment: really thank you for solve the problem.
I read the Chains of Implicit Rules, and the problems are clear for me.
Thank you sincerely.